# How to export variables data with fpdf

Tags: php, html, pdf

This is the code for index which will export what ever is in page under HTML varialbe:

```
<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
$html = 'kkjkjkjkjjkj';
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages($html);
$pdf->AddPage($html);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Here it's exporting it to PDF but here how I can let the `$html` to get export to PDF using FPDF

Comment: My question is how to export php searched to query's result to PDF some very simple and basic library so i cloud use it customarily in any kind of environment

Comment: @abas_rafiq i can't understand your problem ! do you want generate pdf file or send it to browser ?

Comment: @PouyaDarabi here i want to print to pdf the $html variable is it possible here as now it is not printing it.

Comment: @abas_rafiq you want show generated html as seen as in browser to generated  pdf ?
and now it showing tags in generated pdf like <hrml> .... ?????

Comment: i just want this code to change to pdf with the fpdf library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This example clearly exports a (simple) $html variable to a PDF

http://fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto6.htm

Answer (score 1):

1) Have a look at the Manual and Tutorial sections of the [FPDF website](http://fpdf.org/)
There are a lot of simple examples to take a look at.

2) You can't send html code with the AddPage() function. It should be orientation ("P" or "L") and size (like "A4") (see their documentation [here](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/addpage.htm))

3) It is not possible to just insert html into FPDF. You have to cut it up into text, links, images, tables and build the PDF content up just as you build up the HTML. There are some script that do support html input, but even those make mistakes now and then. My advise: instead of creating/building/compiling HTML, generate FPDF elements.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to directly write HTML to a PDF using FPDF - you would have to separate the data into strings, set formatting to them, etc - basically, you will not be dealing with HTML anymore.

However, if you are not limited to FPDF, I would suggest looking into [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/), which can take HTML as an input, and render it to PDF using Webkit rendering engine. It can even take a remote URL and convert it to a PDF on your server.